# Tell me that I exceeded the max title length (150 chars) before I remove focus from the title box

Tags: feature-request, title, character-limit

I was writing a pretty long title and nobody told me that I reached 196 chars already... everything seemed to be ok.

> [image]

But then I removed focus from the title box and... *suddenly* saw that apparently I have already written more than 150 chars!

> [image]

Could it tell me *before* I remove the focus? I mean, it should say that I exceeded the limit *while* I am writing, not *after* I write my title.

Comment: Alternatively it's not actually that hard to prevent additional input after maxlength characters... even plain HTML can do that.

Comment: In addition of that, maybe add a counter... or alternatively, a realtime warning when nearing 150 (from 140?).